# Print which rows have equal values and print the timestamp

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

```
 Sensor    date       Outlier(Y/N)
 1:   1 2014-06-22       Y
 2:   1 2014-06-23       N
 3:   1 2014-06-24       N
 4:   2 2014-06-25       N
 5:   3 2014-06-26       Y
 6:   3 2014-06-27       Y
 7:   3 2014-06-28       Y
 8:   2 2014-06-29       N
 9:   3 2014-06-30       N


df = data.frame(Sensor = c("1","1","1","2","3","3","3","2","3"),
date = c(2014-06-22,2014-06-23,2014-06-24,2014-06-25,2014-06-25,2014-06-26,2014-06-27,2014-06-28,2014-06-29,2014-06-30),
Outlier(Y/N) = c("Y","N","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N", "N"))
```

I would like to print which `Sensor` had more than one consecutive Y value in the `Outlier` column and when (print also the `date` column).
In this case I would expect an output like:

```
   Sensor     Date          N_consecutive_Outlier
        3       2014-06-26              
                2014-06-27              
                2014-06-28              3
```

Obviously the process should be looped as the df has more than 1000 rows

Comment: To make sure people can reproduce your problem, please share the output of `dput(your_dataframe)`.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution can be

```
library(dplyr)

dt1 %>% 
 group_by(Sensor, Outlier.Y.N., new = data.table::rleid(Outlier.Y.N.)) %>% 
 mutate(N_Consec = n()) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 filter(Outlier.Y.N. == 'Y' & N_Consec > 1) %>% 
 select(-new)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Sensor date       Outlier.Y.N. N_Consec
   <int> <chr>      <chr>           <int>
1      3 2014-06-26 Y                   3
2      3 2014-06-27 Y                   3
3      3 2014-06-28 Y                   3
```